# Usar JUnit5 en Netbeans 11

Tags: java, junit, netbeans-11, junit-5

Hola estoy comenzando a ver pruevas unitarias con JUnit5 en Netbeans 11 y resulta que cuando creo los archivos JUnit con el asistente de Netbeans, me genera las anotaciones como:

```
@BeforeEach
@AfterEach
@Test
```

Pero cuando ejecuto determinada prueba, me arroja un error, no creo que sea que sea el codigo a examinar ya que es un ejemplo muy facil.
Pero cuando cambio las anteriores anotaciones por estas:

```
@org.junit.Before
@org.junit.After
@org.junit.Test
```

Si funciona correctamente
No se que estoy haciendo mal, no utilizo maven o si es normal desde ya gracias

Comment: Añade el código para que se te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos confusiones principales con tu código, primeramente el segundo grupo de anotaciones que pones son de [junit-4](/questions/tagged/junit-4), mientras que las primeras son exclusivamente de [junit-5](/questions/tagged/junit-5).

Por ejemplo: [@BeforeEach](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeEach.html).

Segundo, por lo que veo no sabes que librerías estás usando y/o como ver que cosas tienen usando netbeans.

Para ello ve a tu pestaña de proyectos, y en la sección dependencias hallarás tus librerías, las cuales puedes abrir para ver que clases contienen exactamente desde la misma vista.

En netbeans 11 cuando creas un nuevo proyecto y no le especificas la versión que necesitas de JUnit te toma por defecto la versión 5.

Si quieres seguir usando tus anotaciones de junit4, puedes agregar la dependencia llamada **junit-vintage-engine**.

Para cualquier otra duda te recomiendo leer primero la [documentación oficial sobre como migrarte de junit4 a junit5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-running).

[image: Dependencias en netbeans]